# Flexbox align to bottom

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following layout http://jsbin.com/joyetaqase/1/edit?html,css,output

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h2>
      <p>my footer</p>
    </div>

     <div class="col">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum.</h2>
      <p>my footer</p>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Using flexbox I'm trying to make same height and same width to the `.col` divs.

My question is: how can I put the `<p>` to stick at the bottom of the box?

Layout should look like:

[image]

I know I can make the `<p>` absolute and use `bottom:0;` but I want to achieve this with flexbox, is it possible?

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do following way. Give `display: flex;` `flex-direction: column;` to 
`.col` and `flex: 1 0 auto;` to `h2`

```css
.row {
  width: 500px;
  font-family: monospace;
  display:flex;
}

.col {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

h2, p {
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
}

h2 {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
 <div class="row">
    
    
    <div class="col">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</h2>
      <p>my footer</p>
    </div>
    
     <div class="col">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum.</h2>
      <p>my footer</p>
    </div>
    
    
  </div>
```

**[Updated JSBin](http://jsbin.com/kevoloteda/1/edit?html,css,output)**

Comment: @Hiero glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer. when you can

Answer (score 1):

Make `.col` a nested, column-direction flex container.

```
.col {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  /* NEW */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;          /* stack <h2> and <p> vertically */
  justify-content: space-between;  /* align <h2> at top and <p> at bottom */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the parents (`.col`) relative positioning and then give the footers absolute positioning with the attribute `bottom:0px;`.

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/bawexugado/1/)

```
.col {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position:relative;
}

p{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
}
```